# Convert jquery element to html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I have a jQuery element but I have to send it to a function that only accepts HTML elements.  How can I convert the jQuery element to an HTML element?

Comment: You don't really convert it. You just fetch it from the jQuery object by its numeric index.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Try [`myJQueryElement.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or `myJQueryElement[0]`. (`get()` is most useful when you need negative indices, for example, as described in the documentation for `get()`.)

Comment: warning: get(0) will not return the inner elements

Comment: > `negative index` - _A negative index is counted from the end of the matched set, so this example returns the last item in the list._

For ex.`$('div').get(0);`  will return the last `div` element.

Comment: briefly, `$("# foo").get(0)` does the same as `$("# foo")[0]` but `$("# foo").get(0)` is slower.

Answer (score 32):

`$("#foo")[0]` will get you an HTML element.  Using brackets is a tiny bit faster than using `.get()` but not something you'll likely notice unless you are doing it [millions of times](http://jsperf.com/jquery-brackets-vs-get).

Comment: And not even then!  If you run it 10 million times, brackets will take 150 seconds, get will take 170 seconds.  I bet you cannot notice without sitting there counting "1-Mississippi, 2-Mississippi..." Mississippilessly, it's impossible to tell the difference.  Do whichever way you feel is more readable. (BTW, I'm only posting this comment because it gives me the change to use the word  "Mississippilessly" in a sentence.  If anyone wants to discuss the future of the Anglican Church with me, I'm dying to use "antidisestablishmentarianistically".)

Comment: It's ironic that you espoused readability right after using `Mississippilessly` but you're right.  get lets you either convert the jQuery object to an array of DOM objects by calling it without arguments, or get the _n_th from the end by providing a negative argument.  Otherwise it's just a function that uses the brackets.

Comment: omg. this issue has taken literally days from me. thanks for this answer !

Comment: @Malvolio Shouldn't that word just be "establishmentarianistically", since (anti-) and (dis-) are two nots that cancel?

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque — establishmentarianism is the belief you should establish a state church in a country that lacks one; antidisestablishmentarianism is the belief you should continue the state church in a country that already has it.  So far as I can tell, establishmentarianism is quite rare — almost no one wants to *start* a state church. Antidisestablishmentarianism is a common conservative position: "We have always had this nonsense, so we always should."