# changing jquery [object Object] to useable html tag

Tags: arrays, jquery

I have populated an array with a few html image tags that I have created. I'm trying to get the contents of that array to appear as the actual images on the page with the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){        //populates array with images
        var shipImgs = $("#thumb_slider").children().each(function(index, element) {
            var newImg = $("<img />").attr({src: this.src, alt: 'space'}).addClass(index == 0 ? "middle_slot" : (index == 1 ? "left_slot" : "right_slot"));
            imgArr.push(newImg);
        });
```

and then after a button on the page is clicked, it calls a function which should display the images in a div called basic_div with the following line of code:

```
$("#basic_div").html(imgArr[b] + imgArr[a] + imgArr[c]);
```

Instead of seeing the images, all you get is [object Object] when the array is displayed. What is the correct way to "translate" this from a jquery object to actual html code to display the images? If you need to see it in action you can find it here: http://www.digitalbrent.com/lab and then press the increase button. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: using the following returns "[object HTMLImageElement]": $("#basic_div").html(imgArr[b][0] + imgArr[a][0] + imgArr[c][0]); Now I just need to get the image to display... I got this solution from another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114780/convert-jquery-element-to-html-element

Comment: okay found it...

$("#basic_div").append(imgArr[b][0]);

this works because after researching further, I found that .html() converts the object to a string. To actually display the object, I had to use .append(). Thanks for your help guys!

Also for anyone else out there who has this same question, this may be helpful: A problem with dynamically created image

^^^That's where I found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .html function takes a string.  You are passing it objects (or at least you are passing it the dubious 'summation' of objects).  So you need to either build your array with literal strings for the img tags (and attributes), or do something like the following:

```
var newImg = $("<img>");
newImg.attr('src', "tiffany-joy-10.jpg");
newImg.appendTo('#mydiv')
```

I tested it and it works (and she looked good :).

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. I have made this change in my code, but this still does not actually display the images. I have tried using strings and that works, but for my purposes later I will need to populate the array with actual objects so that I can more readily manipulate the id and classes of each one, which would be a real headache if they were strings. Is there something else I need to do to get these to display?

Comment: see my revision...you need to use append or similar functionality