# How to replace the entire class within the element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a HTML like the below,

```js
var divId = document.getElementById('a1');
$(divId).find('#b1').className = "red";
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
  color: #ccc;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1">
  <button id="b1" class="green">green</button>
</div>

<div id= "a2">
  <button id ="b2" class="red">red</button>
</div>
```

How to replace the class `Green` with class `red` ?

Comment: `className` is an attribute of html elements, not of jquery elements. You could use the `attr` function `$(divId).find('#b1').attr('class', 'red');` or vanilla javascript: `document.querySelector('#a1 #b1').className = 'red';`

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to use `attr` & `removeAttr` for classes, as they remove all classes for the element. `addClass` & `removeClass` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up jQuery and JavaScript here.

You can use `className` in a JavaScript referenced element. To change the *class* of a jQuery referenced element you should use [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/). Also, since the attribute [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) is unique in a DOM, simply specifying the [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) in the selector is enough.

```
$('#b1').addClass('class', 'red');
```

**jQuery Solution:**

```js
$('#b1').addClass('red');
```

```css
.Green {
  background-color: green;
  color: #ccc;
}
.red {
  background-color:red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id= "a1">
    <button id ="b1" class = "Green">Green</button>
</div>

<div id= "a2">
    <button id ="b2" class = "red">Red</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Solution:** Instead of using *className*, I will suggest you to use [`DOMTokenList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) to add/remove *class* to an element.

```
var divId = document.getElementById('b1');
divId.classList.add('red');
```

```js
var divId = document.getElementById('b1');
divId.classList.add('red');
```

```css
.Green {
  background-color: green;
  color: #ccc;
}
.red {
  background-color:red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id= "a1">
    <button id ="b1" class = "Green">Green</button>
</div>

<div id= "a2">
    <button id ="b2" class = "red">Red</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(divId).find` returns a jQuery object.

`className` is a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) of HTML Element in vanilla JavaScript.

You do one of the following

- the jQuery [prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method, to set a property on a jQuery object.
- the jQuery [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method, to add a class on a jQuery object.
- convert the jQuery object to an Element ([see SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7114803/994006))
- bypass jQuery itself & use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
$("#a1 #b1").removeClass("Green");
$("#a1 #b1").addClass("red");
```